# HTML5 Canvas getImageData and Translation

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm using an HTML5 Canvas to make a drivable car. After some research, I could make the car go forward, backward and rotate using translate and rotate, like this:

```
ctx.translate(car.x, car.y)
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * car.angle)
let newX = -(car.width / 2)
let newY = -(car.height / 2)
ctx.drawImage(car.img, newX, newY, car.width, car.height)
```

Ok, this is working perfectly. I also need to draw 3 lines in the front of the car (like an obstacle sensor) which I could apply easily because it was already translated and rotated, and the result is this:

[image: screenshot]

Now the problem is, let's take the middle line, for example, I want to "walk" from [x1, y1] to [x2, y2] of this line, checking the color of every pixel, to see if there is a black pixel (obstacle) and if yes, what is the distance from the car (I do this before the line drawing, so the green pixel doesn't bother me).

I found out that I can use getImageData to do this, except that it doesn't get affected by translate, so I get totally lost on how to easily go through the line.

My attempt to a solution was to just increment from X1 to X2, because Y is static (remember, it's translated and rotated, so only X goes forward [that worked for the line drawing]), but, as I said now, getImageData is not affected by translate.

Comment: Where do the "obstacles" come from? Don't read pixels to know where they are, or only do it once if it is really needed. Instead store their positions and then use Maths to know if your lines are colliding or not.

Comment: I actually have their positions and I thought in doing that, but I need the distance also (if it’s between the starting and ending point of the line). I didn’t stop to think if it’s easier this way... I have to consider also that the obstacles are drawn normally while the lines are being drawn with translation and rotation, that influences the coordinates.